# Check the conditions every time after function has been called

Tags: javascript, function, conditional-statements

I have written a function show() - which reveals hidden id classes (I know there is jquery and other methods to do it, but I wanted it this way).

```
//-------------------------
// Function show()
//-------------------------
/**
 * Changes element class name from hide to show in parent element [ default: content ] and hides every other shown classes in that parent element.
 * @param { string } id || none to show  
 * @param { string } parent element id, if provided changes default [ optional ]
 * @params { string } more elements id's to be shown [ optional ]
 * @return { void } changed classes names
**/
```

I have html select:

```
<select name="productName" id="productName">
    <option value="none" selected>Choose product</option>
    <option value="product01">product01</option>
    <option value="product02">product02</option>
    <option value="product03">product03</option>
</select>
```

on which I have event listener which shows normally hidden set of div's:

```
document.getElementById( 'productName' ).addEventListener( 'change', function() {
    if( document.getElementById( 'productName' ).value != 'none' ) {
        if( document.getElementById( 'productName' ).value != 'none' && document.querySelectorAll( '.show' )[ 1 ].id ) show( document.querySelectorAll( '.show' )[ 1 ].id, 'content', 'showProductData' );
    }
} );
```

My condition works perfectly when user changes value of the select, and it shows what it should. But than the user can click a link which again triggers show() function and changes his view and than my problem appears.

The onchange event for select tag, which is obvious, doesn't trigger when user click's the anchor and changes the content of the page.

So I need to check if show() function has been called, and if it was then check again the following condition:

```
    if( document.getElementById( 'productName' ).value != 'none' && document.querySelectorAll( '.show' )[ 1 ].id ) {
        show( document.querySelectorAll( '.show' )[ 1 ].id, 'content', 'showProductData' );
    }
```

Is it possible to do it, without interference in show() function?

Of course setInterval to check this condition do the thing, but it will change what is shown every interval time.

I need to check this condition only once after every call of show() function.
Maybe is there some tricky way to get event listener to the function? something like:

```
show().addEventListener( 'called', function () { above condition } );
```

or any other method to check the value of select tag after every call of function show()?

EDIT. I won't delete all post, but probably I should. I will try to clarify my question.

Probably my example isn't relevant to my question from clear and straight point of view.

Every time the function is called, and it's called every time when user clicks a link or selects something from select tag, I need to check the condition.
While with select tag you need just to add 'onchange' event listener, I don't know how to check this condition when user clicks a link, the page doesn't reloads - its only shows or hides some classes.
I can't check the value of select field in 'onclick' function because I make all 'onclick' functions for all links automatically.

So the only method to achieve my goal is to add some kind of event listener for the function, that every time when function is called checks the condition and does something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, you want to trigger the change event when you dynamically change the value? Easy.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('productName');
//Do what you need to do to change value.
var event = new Event('change');  // Create a new event
elem.dispatchEvent(event); // Fire the event on the element.
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. It would be very useful but it's little bit more complicated in my case. The event is triggered when the user selects something - and than everything is working, but than the user can change what he sees by clicking the link which isn't related to this select and link activates the show() function - thats why I need to add some event listener to the function itself, because than I need to check the value of the select and the condition again. I know it's twisted so I beg your indulgence - I really need it. maybe I can expand the example to show it little bit better.

Comment: Hrm, I don't get exactly what you want then... If you could put samples on your words, it'd be better for understanding. Please edit your question to include the button in your example and use comments to tell us what you want to happen, where.

Comment: I've tried to clarify it little bit more. Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I think you are taking it from the wrong point... My suggestion should work fine. If you need to do/check something everytime a function is called, just do that in the function!! If it is because your onChange event does not fire when a user clicks a button, either make that button trigger the onChange or run the same function than the onChange on click...

Comment: Yes, thank you, you've got right and your thinking is correct, thank you for solution. It is only my problem that with complexity of my page it is much easier to think about checking the function every time it is called than triggering onChange event on the onClick action.